# php7 cannot connect to oracle pooled connection

Tags: oracle11g, connection-pooling, php-7, oci8

this is working fine on cli and on a non pooled connection. when i try the following on cli it works

`sqlplus CCP/"***"@DECCP1ST_POOLED.test.vis`

but when i try to do this in php it throws an error

```
$c = oci_connect('CCP', "***", 'domain.com:33001/DECCP1ST_POOLED.test.vis');
print_r($c);
```

output is

```
Warning: oci_connect(): ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor in
```

in my tnsnames.ora i have

```
DECCP1ST_POOLED.test.vis =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = domain.com)(PORT = 33001))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = POOLED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = DECCP1ST.test.vis)
    )
  )
```

I have followed this [pdf](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/php/php-scalability-ha-twp-128842.pdf).  i have set `oci8.connection_class = SHARED`

Comment: Typo in: `ddomain.de`.

Comment: updated but its same thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [PDF](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/php/php-scalability-ha-twp-128842.pdf) you linked in your question, page 15:

> PHP applications must specify the server type POOLED in the connect string
>   to use DRCP. Using Oracle’s Easy Connect syntax, the PHP call to connect to the  `sales` database on `myhost` would look like:
>
> ```
> $c = oci_pconnect('myuser', 'mypassword', 'myhost/sales:POOLED');
> ```

Based on the above, and your TNS string, you need to use the following in your script:

```
$c = oci_connect('CCP', '***', 'domain.com:33001/DECCP1ST.test.vis:POOLED');
```

It's important to note that you are using the Easy Connect syntax here so the `TNSNAMES.ORA` file is ignored.  Because of this you must use the defined `SERVICE_NAME` (`DECCP1ST.test.vis`) not the TNS alias (`DECCP1ST_POOLED.test.vis`)!